# External Monitor Ghosting (MBP 2016)

Tags: display, displayport

I tried to connect an Eizo Flexscan EV233W to My Macbook Pro using an SVGA cable (suspiciously cheap, but the only one available) and a VGA - Type C adapter.

The image on the external display was ghosted and low-res.
I suspect SVGA itself is a bad choice, although I know nothing about DisplayPorts.

Or perhaps it could be the quality of the cable?

Should I try using my DVI cable that came with the monitor with a DVI to USB-C adapter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself a Belkin [MDP (Thunderbolt video) to HDMI adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013P0JTX0), and a handy HDMI cable you might have lying around, or get a Belkin [all-in-one MDP > HDMI cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013P0JTGC) and it will work. I use both models at work to connect many MacBooks with Thunderbolt video ports to connect to HDMI-equipped monitors.

After years of testing, my institution trusts Belkin adapters to be the most robust and applicable for the task.

*Disclaimer*: I have no financial or other ties to Belkin; just a satisfied user.

Comment: Thank you, the monitor itself has no HDMI port, but I found a DP to Thunderbolt 3 cable I might try.

Comment: There is a Eizo Flexscan EV2333W (notice the third '3' in the model number) which _does_ have a HDMI port. Apologies.